# DHL price not updated on store change

Tags: magento2, shipping, dhl

Steps to reproduce  :

1) Add a product

2) On Filling State and ZIP code the DHL ajax works and fill up the prices
[image]
3) Change the store form USD (Dollar) to EUR (Euro)

Expected result (*)

```
The Price should change as per the currency of the current store selected by the user.
```

Actual result (*)

```
The Price of DHL is the same in all the Currency.
```

[image]